# Monaco: Removing Web APIs from autocomplete/intellisense?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco in an embedded app, where users can write JavaScript to run in our own engine. The engine is far from a web-browser, so we have our own APIs and definitely don't support any web APIs. However, because we run Monaco inside a browser itself, I guess it picks up those APIs and shows them via its (fairly awesome) intellisense widgets. So is there a way to disable this and only show our APIs (which I will feed it using addExtraLibs)?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can specify the default libs you want to include using the `libs` property. Example:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
  target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
  lib: ["es6"]
});
```

From the Typescript docs in the CompilerOptions section:

> Note:
>
> If --lib is not specified a default list of libraries are injected. The 
>   default libraries injected are: 
>   For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
>   For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost

What you want to do is omit the DOM library.

I read somewhere that you can also use `["!DOM"]` to include all defaults **except** `DOM`, although I haven't tested this yet personally.

Make sure you use `typescriptDefaults` for the `typescript` language and `typescript.javascriptDefaults` for the `javascript` language. I think they are basically equivalent with Monaco. This had tripped me up for a while.